# SpriteKit applyforce doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

I have `player` object on my scene and trying to apply some force on it. You can see that I'm applying force on the `update:` method on `MyScene.h` file. But, my `player` is not moving at all. What's happening?

Below is the Player SKSpriteNode.

```
#import "Player.h"
#import "common.h"
@implementation Player
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super initWithImageNamed:@"player.png"];
    self.name = @"player";
    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(22, 50)];
    self.physicsBody.mass = 10;
    self.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    self.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
    self.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = YES;
    self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = ~poopCategory & groundCategory;
    self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = playerCategory;
    self.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = poopCategory;
    self.zPosition = 100;

    return self;
}
@end
```

Next, it's the background that I'm using.

```
#import "Background.h"
#import "common.h"
@implementation Background
+ (Background *) generateBackground {
    Background *background = [[Background alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"RPBackground.png"];
    background.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeFromPoint:CGPointMake(-100, 100) toPoint:CGPointMake(400, 100)];
    background.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = groundCategory;
    background.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = poopCategory | playerCategory;
    background.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = groundCategory;
    background.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    background.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    background.zPosition = 0;
    background.name = @"ground";
    return background;
}
@end
```

Now, this is the main scene.

```
#import "MyScene.h"

@implementation MyScene

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        Background *b = [Background generateBackground];
        [self addChild:b];
        self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -9.8);


        Player *player = [[Player alloc]init];
        player.size = CGSizeMake(30, 60);
        player.position = CGPointMake([UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.width/2, groundLevel+300);

        [self addChild:player];
        self.player = player;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */


}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    [self.player.physicsBody applyForce:CGVectorMake(30, 0)]; // <=------------
}

@end
```

I feel like I'm making some stupid error somewhere... But I can't seem to spot it. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that SpriteKit automatically applies friction, and your force is very small for the mass you set for the Node.  You either need to set a lower mass, a lower level of friction (e.g. 0.0), a lower gravity, or apply more force.  There's nothing specifically wrong with the code, as much as the default friction and gravity combined with your mass and force magnitudes simply result in a motionless Node.

Comment: Anytime.  Just remember that there are other ways around the problem, so another solution may end up looking better depending on what you do with the low-mass node.  In other words, lowering mass can cause other potential problems like changing collision behavior with other objects, etc.